# How to autorun webpack-dev-server when starting debugging RoR session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code

Since Rails 5.1, It's possible to run `rails server` next to `webpack-dev-server`. I have configured debugger in `launch.json` to run rails server. When I start rails server throught vscode, I want it to automatically run `./bin/webpack-dev-server` on background for autocompile javascript changes as another process, but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

I have created task in `tasks.json` to run webpacker but I can't figure out how to combine it with `launch.json`.

Here is my `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "preLaunchTask": "webpack-dev-server",
      "name": "Rails server",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
      "args": [
        "server"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is `tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "webpack-dev-server",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${workspaceRoot}/webpack-dev-server",
      "isBackground": true,
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run debugging and task separately, It's working as expected, but run then automatically when starting debugging not working.

Things I've tried:

1. **run webpack-dev-server with "preLaunchTask"** - problem with this is that "preLaunchTask" waits until webpack-dev-server stop running and after that runs debugging. I need them to run simultaneously next to each other.
2. **Specify webpack-dev-server as another launch configuration and combine these two launches through compond in** `launch.json` - this isn't working, because vscode needs to specify type of launch and shell isn't supported
3. **run task with & at the end to suppress waiting for process finish** - not working

If anybody solved this or know how to achieve running both processes simultaneously through one click, It would be helpful to share this knowledge.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017304/3442759.

In `tasks.json` there needs to be specified `problemMatcher` even when it's not used. Without `problemMatcher` specified, task will not run in the background even when `isBackground` is set to true.

I've created gist with setup steps. https://gist.github.com/tomkra/b1d67a7ae96af34cba78935f15b755b6

So final configuration is:

`launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Rails server",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
      "args": [
        "server"
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "webpack-dev-server"
    }
  ]
}
```

`tasks.json`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "webpack-dev-server",
      "type": "shell",
      "isBackground": true,
      "command": "./bin/webpack-dev-server",
      "problemMatcher": [
        {
          "pattern": [
            {
              "regexp": ".",
              "file": 1,
              "location": 2,
              "message": 3
            }
          ],
          "background": {
            "activeOnStart": true,
            "beginsPattern": ".",
            "endsPattern": ".",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```