# Stuck waiting for prelaunch task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to run my debug environment as a Poetry session, so I can properly debug encapsulated.

So, my `launch.json` is straightforward:

```json
        {
            "name": "Poetry",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5710
            },
            "preLaunchTask": "poetryDebugSession",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
```

and I adapted my `tasks.json` to try to launch `debugpy` in Poetry first (this works if I manually run some code in the terminal)

```json
{
            "label": "poetryDebugSession",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "poetry",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "python",
                "-m",
                "debugpy",
                "--log-to-stderr",
                "--wait-for-client",
                "--listen",
                "5710",
                "${relativeFile}",
                "&"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "clear": true
            },
            "group": "test",
            "isBackground": true,
            "runOptions":{
                "instanceLimit": 1
            },
            // This task is run before the launch.json task. Since it needs to run in the
            // background and not wait for completion, though, we need to jump through hoops
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "owner": "python",
                    "fileLocation": "absolute",
                    "pattern": [
                        {
                            "regexp": "^\\s+File \"(.*)\", line (\\d+), in (.*)$",
                            "file": 1,
                            "line": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "regexp": "^\\s+(.*)$",
                            "message": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "background": {
                        "activeOnStart": true,
                        "beginsPattern": "^D[0-9\\.: \\+]+wait_for_client",
                        "endsPattern": ".*",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

When I start debugging, the task is properly launched, and debugpy gets all the way to the message I am waiting for that I want the preluanch task to be marked as "ready":

```
> Executing task: poetry run python -m debugpy --log-to-stderr --wait-for-client --listen 5710 d:\path\to\myfile.py <
# stuff

I+00000.344: pydevd is connected to adapter at 127.0.0.1:61443

D+00000.344: wait_for_client()
```

I could have *sworn* I had this working last week but as of 1.58.2 after a restart this morning it doesn't progress past `wait_for_client()` display, so the debugger never attaches. I'm also a little suspicious that `${relativeFile}` includes a full path in my output but that probably doesn't matter.

It should be clear from the code above that I derived my initial implementation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017304/1877527 , but still no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `debugpy` team helped me find an answer:

https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/676#issuecomment-886041838

```json
{
            "name": "Python: Poetry current file",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${env:USERPROFILE}/.poetry/bin/poetry",
            "python": "<path/to/bare/bones/python>",
            "args": ["run", "python", "${file}"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        }
```

It worked for me even without the `python` argument, since my primary dev machine just has one active Python installation.